# iOS Programming in Swift and memory management

Tags: swift, xcode, xctest

I'm fairly new to iOS swift programing.  I'm currently working on a project of mine and have been very careful to only capture weak references to self, check that deinit is called etc. But I've noticed that the memory indicator in the Debug navigator in xcode still slightly increases over time.  After multiple (dozens of instating a view controller and then dismissing it), I noticed the memory had gone up from 21.7MB to 23.1MB.  Maybe it's my paranoia, but I decided to do a test.

So I have a clean Xcode project.  The default project `ViewController` has the following code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = .systemGray
        
        let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
        button.setTitle("Show", for: [])
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(showVC), for: .touchUpInside)
        
        view.addSubview(button)
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            button.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            button.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
        ])
    }
    
    
    @objc func showVC() {
        let newVC = SecondVC()
        self.present(newVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

The second VC has the following code:

```
class SecondVC: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = .systemYellow
        
        let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
        button.setTitle("Close", for: [])
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(closeVC), for: .touchUpInside)
        
        view.addSubview(button)
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            button.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            button.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor, constant: -20),
        ])
    }
    
    
    @objc func closeVC() {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
}
```

I then built an XCTestCase with the following code:

```
class testingMemoryUITests: XCTestCase {

    override func setUpWithError() throws {
        // Put setup code here. This method is called before the invocation of each test method in the class.

        // In UI tests it is usually best to stop immediately when a failure occurs.
        continueAfterFailure = false

        // In UI tests it’s important to set the initial state - such as interface orientation - required for your tests before they run. The setUp method is a good place to do this.
    }

    override func tearDownWithError() throws {
        // Put teardown code here. This method is called after the invocation of each test method in the class.
    }

    func testVCPresentation() {
        
        let app = XCUIApplication()
        
        let showButton = app/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.staticTexts["Show"]/*[[".buttons[\"Show\"].staticTexts[\"Show\"]",".staticTexts[\"Show\"]"],[[[-1,1],[-1,0]]],[0]]@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/
        showButton.tap()
        
        let closeButton = app/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.staticTexts["Close"]/*[[".buttons[\"Close\"].staticTexts[\"Close\"]",".staticTexts[\"Close\"]"],[[[-1,1],[-1,0]]],[0]]@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/
        closeButton.tap()
    }

    
    func testLaunchPerformance() throws {
        if #available(macOS 10.15, iOS 13.0, tvOS 13.0, watchOS 7.0, *) {
            // This measures how long it takes to launch your application.
            measure(metrics: [XCTApplicationLaunchMetric()]) {
             
                XCUIApplication().launch()

                var applicationLaunchCounter = 0
                while applicationLaunchCounter < 100 {
                
                    XCUIApplication().activate()

                    var counter = 0
                    while counter < 100 {
                        testVCPresentation()
                        counter += 1
                        print("Counter: ", applicationLaunchCounter, counter)
                    }
                    
                    XCUIApplication().terminate()
                    applicationLaunchCounter += 1
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the above code, it is firing up the app, then it will fire up the second view controller and dismiss it 100 times.  The app is then dismissed and we then start all over again for 100 times.  So in total, the test will trigger this 10,000 times.  At the start of this test, I started with 21.7MB, by the end, the memory was at 83.2MB.  CPU stayed low for the entire test at 4%.

Is this something I should be worried about?   Whilst these numbers are low, on a project like mine, that has a lot more views etc, the numbers are a bit higher and I end the test at around 162MB.

**Update Aug 26**
I've run the tests in both the simulator as well as on a physical device and the same behaviour is observed.

I've also used instruments to check for Leaks and it's not picking up any.

Comment: Are you running this code on actual iOS device or on Simulator?

Comment: Did you got any debugging issue?

Comment: Running on the simulator.  No debugging issues

Comment: Are you running under the Release configuration?

Comment: How do I check that?

Comment: It's in the scheme editor, you are probably running tests using the Debug configuration, which is not as diligent about cleaning up memory. Which is why if you look at your settings for Profiling - it runs in Release by default. If you are worried about memory then a better tool would be to use Instruments.

Comment: Please check memory graph after presenting and dismissing view controllers a couple of times and see if there more instances of this view controllers than there are actually needed.

Comment: @PatrykBudzinski - how do I go about doing this?  I look at the graph but can't see any view controllers listed so I must be looking in the wrong place.

Comment: @Anthony You need to search for the instances in the debug navigator which is located on the left panel. Do this after graph building is completed.